# AVPlayerLayer animates frame changes

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, movie

Whenever I change the frame of my AVPlayerLayer, the video is not resized immediately, but animated to the new size.

For example: I change the frame from (0, 0, 100, 100) to (0, 0, 400, 400), the view's frame is changed immediately, but the video's size is animated to the new size.

Has anyone encountered this issue? And if yes does someone know a way to disable the default animation?

Thanks!

Comment: Funny, I have the opposite issue: I can't get animations to work on AVPlayerLayer!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try disabling implicit actions and using zero length animations:

```
CALayer *videolayer = <# AVPlayerLayer #>
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
CGRect rect = videolayer.bounds;
rect.size.width /= 3;
rect.size.height /= 3;
videolayer.bounds = rect; 
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Yes, seems to work fine. Cheers. A note to others: this requires the QuartzCore.framework to use CATransaction

Answer (score 8):

This is what I used:

```
AVPlayerLayer * playerLayer = <# AVPlayerLayer #>;
playerLayer.frame = <# CGRect #>;
[playerLayer removeAllAnimations];
```

I hope this helps. I don't know if its best practices, but it works for me.
It seems that whenever ".frame" or "setFrame" is used, it adds animation to the layer.

Comment: Tried this (in swift) but placed the playerLayer.removeAllAnimations() in the wrong place. You need to call this directly after every time you change the frame, not when you create the layer.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and cleanest way to deal with this is to create a UIView subclass that has AVPlayerLayer as its layerClass. When doing this the AVPlayerLayer will behave just like a regular UIView layer. You can change the frame of the view instead of the layer and no implicit animations will happen.

**AVPlayerLayerView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AVPlayerLayerView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;

@end
```

**AVPlayerLayerView.m**

```
#import "AVPlayerLayerView.h"

@implementation AVPlayerLayerView

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}

- (AVPlayerLayer *)playerLayer {
    return (AVPlayerLayer *)self.layer;
}

@end
```

You can now do this:

```
playerLayerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400);
```

To associate the AVPlayerLayer with an AVPlayer simply do this:

```
playerLayerView.playerLayer.player = player;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you use ?:

```
- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player {
    [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
    [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResize];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do in **Swift** right after changing the `playerLayer`'s `frame`:

```
playerLayer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in **Swift 4** via the following:

```
    var videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0)
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    var rect = videoLayer.bounds
    rect.size.width /= 3
    rect.size.height /= 3
    videoLayer.bounds = rect
    CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this, what will help in some cases:

adding custom 'setFrame:' setter in view that holds the player layer

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame:frame];

    self.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
}
```