# Add multiple MPMoviePlayerController on UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm new at iOS development;

I add two `MPMoviePlayerController` on my scrollView for play audio file.
All is well but problem is any one **media player** such like

[image]

I am sure that my `URL` of file is proper. Then is issue here.

I don't know that Apple's iOS provide feature that we can add only one media player??

Please give me any suggestion.

It is very important for my application to add two `MPMoviePlayerController` so user can display **TWO Media** player.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can add multiple `MPMoviePlayerController` objects, though only one can play a file at one time.
This is from Apple Documentation:

> Note: Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects
>   and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a
>   time can play its movie.

Here is the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Ok.. thanks for your golden replay, have any solution for it?? how can i display two media player ?

Comment: I dont think there is a a solution. This is how Apple has made it.

Answer (score 3):

I know that you can play multiple videos in a single view by using the Apple [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3) framework (rather than MPMoviePlayerController).  I imagine this is true of audio files as well.

Here is a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368112/multiple-mpmovieplayercontroller-instances) with tips about implementing AVFoundation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with multiple `MPMoviePlayerController`s in a `UIScrollView`, my solution being to add the media programatically to `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.

Not ideal because you then have to work around the fact the media isn't there until the scroll is finished but a nice bit of animation is working quite well in my case.